# How do you use Get-Content with the exclude parameter?

Tags: powershell

I'm learning PowerShell and going through the parameters for `Get-Content`. I'm not sure how to use `-Exclude` with `Get-Content`.

I'm assuming it's supposed to be something like this:

```
Get-Content myfile.txt -Exclude "some string"
```

Am I using it wrong because it's not excluding some string in myfile.txt.

Comment: You are using it wrong. Read the `get-help -full get-content` for what it does, and you'll see it has nothing to do with excluding lines from the file, but it's to do with excluding files if you're using a wildcard path parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Exclude` parameter does not apply to the content of files.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-3.0):

> **`-Exclude`**
>
> Omits the specified items. The value of this parameter qualifies the **Path** parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as "*.txt". Wildcards are permitted.